# Проблема с выводом данных

Tags: php, mysql

Возникли такие трудности.

В первом блоке есть запрос, который выводит урон оружия по убыванию:

```
SELECT * FROM `weapon_statistics` ORDER BY `weapon_damage` DESC LIMIT 0, 9
```

На 4 позиции мне вывело M4. В следующей блоке вывожу точность стрельбы:

```
SELECT * FROM `weapon_statistics` ORDER BY `weapon_accuracy` DESC, `weapon_damage` DESC LIMIT 0, 9
```

Тут M4 на первом месте.

Как мне во втором блоке возле названия и значения точности стрельбы вывести ее позицию из первого блока?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY weapon_damage DESC) damage_rank
FROM weapon_statistics 
ORDER BY weapon_accuracy DESC, 
         weapon_damage DESC
```

Comment: А как вывести полученные данные?

Comment: Получение данных и вывод полученных данных - два разных (и, в общем, не связанных между собой) вопроса.

Comment: Так как раз в вопросе я спросил про вывод

Comment: Вы вообще выводить хоть как-то хоть что-то что-то умеете? сто пудов умеете... ну так вот - возьмите мой запрос, который даст все данные в ОДНОМ наборе (а не часть тут, остальное там), и выводите полученное как любой обычный результат запроса к одной таблице.